# Keys Loss in Redis

Tags: redis

I have started using Redis newly.

After 10 to 12 hours of non usageof my application, I see the keys missing from redis cache.

This is a non confidential staging environment and hence no security on redis is obtained.

Happened twice in 2 days of time.

Note : redis is running in standalone.

I have tried connecting from wildfly app Server and when the application     server is down at night time , this problem is observed in the morning.

After redis saves to the disk, does redis remove the key from in-memory ?

I have tried getting the statistics and have check TTL of the keys which was -1.
The statistics says :
expired_keys:0
evicted_keys:0
maxmemory increased to 6GB and cant be reached which is quite high than my input size
Statistics below
Redis running as a standalone on CentOS

```
  127.0.0.1:6379>  info
  # Server
  redis_version:3.2.12
  redis_git_sha1:00000000
  redis_git_dirty:0
  redis_build_id:7897e7d0e13773f
  redis_mode:standalone
  os:Linux 3.10.0-957.12.2.el7.x86_64 x86_64
  arch_bits:64
  multiplexing_api:epoll
  gcc_version:4.8.5
  process_id:20830
  run_id:eea4f3ccc73fc20e16ef20441393b1189050fdb8
  tcp_port:6379
  uptime_in_seconds:208558
  uptime_in_days:2
  hz:10
  lru_clock:3417026
  executable:not shown
  config_file:not shown 

  # Clients
  connected_clients:1
  client_longest_output_list:0
  client_biggest_input_buf:0
  blocked_clients:0

  # Memory
  used_memory:814024
  used_memory_human:794.95K
  used_memory_rss:8163328
  used_memory_rss_human:7.79M
  used_memory_peak:1250632
  used_memory_peak_human:1.19M
  total_system_memory:8201187328
  total_system_memory_human:7.64G
  used_memory_lua:40960
  used_memory_lua_human:40.00K
  maxmemory:6442450944
  maxmemory_human:6.00G
  maxmemory_policy:noeviction
  mem_fragmentation_ratio:10.03
  mem_allocator:jemalloc-3.6.0

  # Persistence
  loading:0
  rdb_changes_since_last_save:0
  rdb_bgsave_in_progress:0
  rdb_last_save_time:1563697205
  rdb_last_bgsave_status:ok
  rdb_last_bgsave_time_sec:0
  rdb_current_bgsave_time_sec:-1
  aof_enabled:0
  aof_rewrite_in_progress:0
  aof_rewrite_scheduled:0
  aof_last_rewrite_time_sec:-1
  aof_current_rewrite_time_sec:-1
  aof_last_bgrewrite_status:ok
  aof_last_write_status:ok

  # Stats
  total_connections_received:119
  total_commands_processed:378
  instantaneous_ops_per_sec:0
  total_net_input_bytes:26750
  total_net_output_bytes:115176
  instantaneous_input_kbps:0.00
  instantaneous_output_kbps:0.00
  rejected_connections:0
  sync_full:0
  sync_partial_ok:0
  sync_partial_err:0
  expired_keys:0
  evicted_keys:0
  keyspace_hits:165
  keyspace_misses:27
  pubsub_channels:0
  pubsub_patterns:0
  latest_fork_usec:928
  migrate_cached_sockets:0

 # Replication
 role:master
 connected_slaves:0
 master_repl_offset:0
 repl_backlog_active:0
 repl_backlog_size:1048576
 repl_backlog_first_byte_offset:0
 repl_backlog_histlen:0

 # CPU
 used_cpu_sys:130.68
 used_cpu_user:60.20
 used_cpu_sys_children:0.26
 used_cpu_user_children:0.04

 # Cluster
 cluster_enabled:0

  Last action on Redis -valid hits from our application

  14649:C 21 Jul 01:17:31.508 * RDB: 4 MB of memory used by copy-on-write
  20830:M 21 Jul 01:17:31.605 * Background saving terminated with success
  20830:M 21 Jul 01:32:32.018 * 1 changes in 900 seconds. Saving...
  20830:M 21 Jul 01:32:32.019 * Background saving started by pid 14817
  14817:C 21 Jul 01:32:32.021 * DB saved on disk
  14817:C 21 Jul 01:32:32.021 * RDB: 4 MB of memory used by copy-on-write
  20830:M 21 Jul 01:32:32.119 * Background saving terminated with success
  20830:M 21 Jul 03:03:44.634 * 1 changes in 900 seconds. Saving...
  20830:M 21 Jul 03:03:44.636 * Background saving started by pid 15843
  15843:C 21 Jul 03:03:44.638 * DB saved on disk
  15843:C 21 Jul 03:03:44.638 * RDB: 4 MB of memory used by copy-on-write
  20830:M 21 Jul 03:03:44.736 * Background saving terminated with success
  20830:M 21 Jul 03:18:45.076 * 1 changes in 900 seconds. Saving...
  20830:M 21 Jul 03:18:45.079 * Background saving started by pid 16040
  16040:C 21 Jul 03:18:45.080 * DB saved on disk
  16040:C 21 Jul 03:18:45.081 * RDB: 4 MB of memory used by copy-on-write
  20830:M 21 Jul 03:18:45.179 * Background saving terminated with success
```

Actual Results I am expecting the keys to be present even on non usage of redis

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, Redis doesn't remove keys from memory when saving to disc.

Your uptime is ok(so no data loss on restart), so it left us with only two theories:

- You either deleting your keys somehow in your client app (or somebody else if Redis is exposed to public)
- More probably you're trying to access keys using wrong key names. Try to check your Redis for all stored keys using `CLI`.

Comment: Thanks @Evgenii Malikov.
The second option is not an option ,as I have checked with redis-cli an as well as monitor , so the exposure to public may be a concern.
I have started a monitoring process today at redis-cli to see the changes